# Как вытянуть правильно инфу из базы с поддоменами?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, какой запрос ввести, чтобы вытащить с базы все заголовки статей авторов со всех поддоменов. По такому запросу:

```
SELECT s.site_description AS SITE,
       c.channel_title AS SECTION,
       a.title AS article,
       ct.title AS author
  FROM wt_channel_titles AS a
  LEFT JOIN wt_channel_data AS d ON d.entry_id = a.entry_id
  LEFT JOIN wt_channels AS c ON c.channel_id = a.channel_id
  LEFT JOIN wt_sites AS s ON s.site_id = a.site_id
  LEFT JOIN wt_relationships AS r ON r.rel_id = d.field_id_231
  LEFT JOIN wt_channel_titles AS ct ON ct.entry_id = r.rel_child_id
 WHERE c.channel_name IN ('articles', 'news')
   AND d.field_id_231 != 0
 LIMIT 0, 1000
```

выводится список из 233 строк авторов с одного поддомена.
Вот таким запросом:

```
SELECT s.site_description AS site,
       c.channel_title AS section,
       a.title AS article,
       ct.title AS author
  FROM wt_channel_titles AS a
  LEFT JOIN wt_channel_data AS d ON d.entry_id = a.entry_id
  LEFT JOIN wt_channels AS c ON c.channel_id = a.channel_id
  LEFT JOIN wt_sites AS s ON s.site_id = a.site_id
  LEFT JOIN wt_relationships AS r ON r.rel_id = d.field_id_231
  LEFT JOIN wt_channel_titles AS ct ON ct.entry_id = r.rel_child_id
 WHERE c.channel_name IN ('articles', 'news')
 LIMIT 0, 5000
```

(лимит можно увеличивать) выводятся уже заголовки статей со всех поддоменов, но напротив автора статьи стоит null. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести инфу правильно?

Comment: Что за поле `field_id_231`? Опишите структуру используемых таблиц и связи между ними.

Comment: структура
wt_channel_titles ( 
entry_id
site_id
channel_id
author_id
pentry_id
forum_topic_id
ip_address
title
url_title)
wt_channel_data (
entry_id
site_id
field_ft_187
...
field_id_232
)
wt_channels (
channel_id
site_id
channel_name
channel_title
channel_url
channel_description
total_entries
total_comments
last_entry_date
last_comment_date
)
wt_sites ( 
site_id
site_label
site_name
site_description
)
wt_relationships ( 
rel_id
rel_parent_id
rel_child_id
reverse_rel_data
)
wt_channel_titles (
entry_id
site_id
channel_id
author_id
forum_topic_id
ip_address
title
url_title
)

Comment: оба приведённых запроса отличаются только тем, что в первом запросе есть условие `d.field_id_231!=0`, вы так и не объяснили что это за поле. Можете создать пример своей базы на http://sqlfiddle.com/ забить пару строк тестовых данных и сказать что именно вы хотите получить в результате своих запросов?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: "оба приведённых запроса отличаются только тем" - естественно, потому что я их и задавал. по полю  d.field_id_231 могу сказать только, что в нем содержатся куски статей из поддомена, результаты которого и выводятся. мне самому только дали эту базу, сказали извлечь с нее все статьи для переноса: если бы я знал все связи и взаимосвязи, то сам бы разобрался. все то, что по ссылке - это детские примеры, т.к. сама база огромная - более 500 метров и выкачивается каждый раз неполной, поэтому продемонстрировать не могу.

Comment: mysqldump может делать дамп структуры без данных. в этой структуре есть внешние ключи, которые могут подсказать связи между таблицами?

Comment: а с помощью какого запроса можно сделать такой дамп?

Comment: @Вася, оформляйте свои ответы в комментариях с кодом, как ответ, затем переквалифицируйте их как комментарии, чтобы было удобно читать ваш программный код).Это просто добрый совет.

Comment: на stackoverflow не приветствуется длительное обсуждение в комментариях, все новые вопросы следует задавать отдельно. [mysqldump -d](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) позволяет сделать дамп структуры без данных.